# Must declare the scalar variable '@Jobcode'

Tags: sql, set, declare

```
DECLARE @JOBCODE NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @JOBCODE = (SELECT TOP 1 JOBCODE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEENAME = 'SCHIPPERT, RALF')
```

I am trying to declare a variable but getting error:

> Must declare the scalar variable

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're trying to assign a SELECT statement directly to a variable without using the SELECT itself for the assignment.

```
DECLARE @JOBCODE NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT TOP 1 @JOBCODE = JOBCODE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEENAME = 'SCHIPPERT, RALF';
```

Here you use the SELECT statement to assign the result directly to the @JOBCODE variable via using @JOBCODE = JOBCODE

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MHzItrC-)